# Is it possible to join reference data into a nested dict in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to join two pandas data frames - the "left" table, which contains a column with a complex type (an array of dicts) and the "right" table is a flat reference table.

pseudo table representation of these as follows

**left_df**

| parent_id | array_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{id: 1}, {id: 3}] |
| 2 | [{id: 2}, {id: 4}] |

**right_df**

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one |
| 2 | two |
| 3 | three |
| 4 | four |

I'm aiming to lookup/join the values from the right df into the array in the array_column of the left df using id's, but have found this quite tricky.

**desired outcome**

| parent_id | array_column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{id: 1, value:'one'}, {id: 3, value: 'three'}] |
| 2 | [{id: 2, value: 'two'}, {id: 4, value: 'four'}] |

My naive approach to start with was to use a merge, as per the following approach.

```
desired_df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, how='outer', left_on = 'array_column.['id']', right_on = 'id')
```

Obviously this failed - not quite sure how I can progress further. Effectively the aim is to lookup reference data onto dicts within an array, but after much searching I've not been able to articulate the problem well enough for a google result to show something that can help.

Appreciate any guidance anyone can share on this, whether using pandas or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With merge it would look like:

```
temp = left_df.explode("array_column")
temp = temp.merge(
    right_df, left_on=temp["array_column"].apply(lambda x: x.get("id")), right_on="id"
).drop(columns="id")
temp["array_column"] = temp.apply(
    lambda x: {**x["array_column"], "value": x["value"]}, axis=1
)
out = temp.groupby("parent_id")["array_column"].agg(list).reset_index()
print(out)

   parent_id                                      array_columns
0          1  [{'id': 1, 'value': 'one'}, {'id': 3, 'value':...
1          2  [{'id': 2, 'value': 'two'}, {'id': 4, 'value':...
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this answer! I was able to adapt the lambda to bring through more columns from right_df, and then extended the groupby to bring include more columns from the left_df. Have set this as the accepted answer as it was easier to extend in this way in the context of dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Merge might not be the right approach since you are storing complex object types like list of dict having said that you can create a dictionary from the right_df then use it with `map` to substitute and append the new key-val pairs in left_df

```
d = right_df.set_index('id')['value']
left_df['array_column'] = left_df['array_column'].map(lambda x: [{**y, 'value': d.get(y['id'])} for y in x])
```

Result

```
   parent_id                                              array_column
0          1  [{'id': 1, 'value': 'one'}, {'id': 3, 'value': 'three'}]
1          2   [{'id': 2, 'value': 'two'}, {'id': 4, 'value': 'four'}]
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham this was very helpful. I was able to implement this solution with my use case.

The example I shared was generic, and in the real use case, there are multiple properties I want to map to the array column (value1, value2 etc), which is why I was looking at merge (as this brings across all columns). Is it possible to map several columns to the array using this method?